# how to avoid this service pack installation(Service pack is very huge size setup and its taking looong time to get the application installed)

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, visual-studio, deployment

I've created a single setup containing my .net application and database which runs under the .net 3.5 framework.

My application can only run if we install the SQLExpress service pack - how can I avoid this service pack installation>

The service pack is huge and it is taking a long time to get the application installed.

Could you please suggest how I can avoid this long installation?

Comment: Why does your program run only if the service pack is installed?

Comment: here i'm using sqlexpress.mdf database,you've any idea?

Comment: Did that answer my question? I can't tell...

Answer (score 0):

> My application can only run if we install the SQLExpress service pack - how can I avoid this service pack installation>

So you want to have the service pack, but not install it?

Have you looked into a slipstreamed set up? (Ie combining RTM and SP into a single installer.)

Knowing what version of SQL Express you are targeting would help (and how you deal with a latter version of SQL Express already present).

Comment: Hi Richard..thanks for the quick response, you have any tutorials to follow the slipstreamed technique? Im usingg sql express version 2005. I just wanted to reduce the installation time as its taking too long to install.

Comment: @Ambarish: not for 2005 (I've done it for full SQL Server 2008: found lots of instructions, including on MSDN, with a search).

Comment: it is a desktop applcn,so SQLCE can provide SQLExpress(.mdf)services.

Comment: @Ambarish: This advice is free: you won't get anywhere chasing like that. And you need to be clear about what you want from what edition and version of SQL -- this jumping around just confuses it. I suggest editing you question to clearly define what you are trying to do, why you are and what you've tried.